# Firebase Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds})

Tags: reactjs

First I query for my data from firebase:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      async function fetchData() {
        const request = await db
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user)
          .collection("notifications")
          .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
            setNotifications(
              snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
            )
          );
      }
      fetchData();
    } else {
      setNotifications([]);
    }
  }, [user]);
```

The query returns this:

[image]

Now, when I try to render the data:

```js
   <div className="notifications">
      {notifications.map((notification) => (
        <NotificationContainer
          notificationType={notification.notificationType}
          notificationFrom={notification.notificationFrom}
          timestamp={notification.timestamp}
          linkId={notification.linkId}
        />
      ))}
```

When I try to render the data on the page, I get the following error:

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I think there may be something wrong in the day I am reading the data from my `notifications` array

Comment: Would be great if you could just store that data in a variable and send a sandbox link with a reproducible example, seems like the part notification.timestamp is throwing the error since it's an object

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is somewhere in your code, you're trying to render object.
Something like this will give you that error "Object are not valid React Child"

```
const obj = { a: 1 }

const SomeComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>{obj}</div>
  )
}
```

In your case, I assume "notification" is an object that look like this, firebase return timestamp in object format

```
notification: {
  timestamp: {
    seconds: 1700000000,
    nanoseconds: 1700000000000,
  }
}
```

Thus in  must have somewhere that try to render this object

```
return (
  ...
  <div>{timestamp}</div>
  ...
)
```

If you find this and change to

```
return (
  ...
  <div>{timestamp.seconds}</div>
  ...
)
```

Should make the error disappear.

Answer (score 1):

So I was using the `timestamp` firebase field. And when I tried to render it, the nasty error I was talking about pops up.

The timestamp is not a string and most likely an object.